# To calculate information gain

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mutual-information

I want to calculate information gain by using this formula-

[image]

Here, probabilities
are interpreted on an event space
of documents (e.g., P(t¯k, ci) denotes the
probability that, for a random document
x, term tk does not occur in x and x
belongs to category ci), and are estimated
by counting occurrences in the training
set

What is the definition of P(t) and P(c) in these cases?

Answer (score 0):

Below the summation signs $t$ and $c$ are defined to be members of the sets $\{c_{i}, \overline{c_{i}}\}$ and $\{t_{k}, \overline{t_{k}}\}$.  This gives the definition of $t$ and $c$.
Based on this description, I would thinkg $P(t)$ refers to the probability of term $t$ occuring or not occurring overall and $P(c)$ being the probability of category $c$ occuring or not occuring, depending on what part of the summation you are in.

Hope this helps!